# Use of dictionary use for discord.py

Tags: python, dictionary, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot and one of the features is that it writes what tasks/homework(s) you have to do. And I made it so that people can write tasks for other people. How can I achieve this? All I have is a way to write a task but there isn't a way to print it. Can someone help me with an easy way to make this dictionary for discord.py? Here is an example of the unfinished code that I have:

````
elif str(message.content).lower() == ">homeworkadd":
     await message.channel.send("Enter the homework subject you want to add. Start your text with '>hs *subject and what to do*'")

elif ">hs" in message.content:
    whattodo = str(message.content[4:])
    homework.append(whattodo)
    await message.channel.send("Your subject and your definition ('{}') have been installed successfully!".format(whattodo))
elif str(message.content).lower() == ">homework":
    print(homework)
    await message.content.send(homework)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but I would recommend you use a database of at least save the homework to a file. If your bot crashes or you need to restart it, then you will loose all the homework that is stored in the database.

I recommend you use a database, which can be very simple to set and write up (Have a look https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) . It also allows you to scale up/add more features a little bit better. The base line is, avoid saving it to a dictionary/list/etc.

Comment: Firebase real-time db has 1 GB free plan which might be useful and also it is much more flexible

Comment: I don't really understand how to use a database. I searched up a tutorial and I still don't understand. Can you recommend me something that will help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think I learnt it off this... https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm